# unmarshalling nested complex object using rdf:about

Tags: xml, jaxb, unmarshalling

I'm having trouble unmarshalling nested complex object. In below xml example "Racing" has a RacingTicket obj. That can be reached by the rdf:about link, which is a restful service call to get RacingTicket.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:hl="http://racing.com/horses/holding-location">
    <title type="text">Create Racing Event</title>
    <id>http://www.racing.com/</id>
    <content type="application/xml">
    <racing xmlns="http://racing.com/schema/horses">
        <racingTicket rdf:about="https://racing.com/fast/racingTicket/asdf-asfd-asdf-asdf-asdf" />
        <tracks>
        <track>
            <title>ABX</title>
            <amount>560</amount>
        </track>
        </tracks>
        <racingId>001</racingId>
    </racing>
    </content>
</entry>



Java class

@XmlRootElement
public class Racing implements Serializable {

    @AtomId( prefixUrl = "http://racing.com/fast/racingTicket/" )
    private String id;

    private RacingTicket racingTicket;

    private Tracks tracks;

    private BigDecimal racingId;



    public RacingTicket getRacingTicket() {

    return racingTicket;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setRacingTicket( RacingTicket racingTicket ) {

    this.racingTicket = racingTicket;
    }
```

The object returned by jaxb unmarshaler contains all values as null for racingTicket class. 
Please advise, any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a JAXB `XmlAdapter` to convert between a link and an instance of `RacingTicket`.

**Example**

- [Adding links to REST Responses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235952/adding-links-to-rest-responses/5236166#5236166)